# Node.js express-session regenerates itself new session ID and sets new sid cookie after expiry

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

```
session= require('express-session')
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)

@use \json, session: { secret: 'secret', store: new RedisStore, httpOnly: true, expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 1000), cookie: { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 1000), maxAge: 10000 } } ,'bodyParser',@app.router
```

My post login action is as, here i am printing the @request.session on console:

```
@post '/_login': ->
console.log @request.session
```

If i refreshes my post login page after 10 seconds of session expiry or click on any other link inside my application, it itself generates and assigns/resets cookie a new sid to the client.
If session expires I don't want it to regenerate the session itself  and pass new sid to the browser.

What's wrong here, Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/session#saveuninitialized

Comment: @robertklep saveuninitialized is for not to store, this is something not related to it, i guess..i tried doing it false, but still the same.

Comment: Why do you want to preserve the session after expiry? That is precisely the point of setting an expiration, to make the session invalid and force the client to restart the authentication/validation process.

Comment: @LuisDelgado I don't want to preserve the session after expiry at all.
 Actually, It's been assigning the new session id automatically after session expires. I dont want it to assign new session id automatically. How can i prevent this?